# Why dockered centos doesn't recognize pip?

Tags: docker, pip

I want to create a container with python and few packages over centos. I've tried to run several commands inside raw centos container. Everything worked fine I've installed everything I want. Then I created `Dockerfile` with the same commands executed via `RUN` and I'm getting `/bin/sh: pip: command not found` What could be wrong? I mean the situation at all. Why everything could be executed in the command line but not be executed with `RUN`? I've tried both variants:

```
RUN command
RUN command
RUN pip install ...
```

and

```
RUN command\
    && command\
    && pip install ...
```

Commands that I execute:

```
from centos

run yum install -y centos-release-scl\
    && yum install -y rh-python36\
    && scl enable rh-python36 bash\
    && pip install django
```

**UPD:** Full path to the pip helped. What's wrong?

Comment: @tgogos My question is more about the problem at all, not about this case. Why commands run fine from inside of container but not via `RUN`

Comment: Another approach would be to start `FROM centos/python-36-centos7
` which is on [docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/r/centos/python-36-centos7/)

Answer (score 2):

You need to install pip first using

```
yum install python-pip
```

or if you need python3 (from epel)

```
yum install python36-pip
```

When not sure, ask `yum`:

```
yum whatprovides /usr/bin/pip

python2-pip-18.1-1.fc29.noarch : A tool for installing and managing Python 2 packages
Repo        : @System
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/bin/pip

python2-pip-18.1-1.fc29.noarch : A tool for installing and managing Python 2 packages
Repo        : updates
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/bin/pip

python2-pip-18.0-4.fc29.noarch : A tool for installing and managing Python 2 packages
Repo        : fedora
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/bin/pip
```

*This output is from Fedora29, but you should get similar result in Centos/RHEL*

**UPDATE**

From comment

> But when I execute same commands from docker run -ti centos everything
>   is fine. What's the problem?

Maybe your `PATH` is broken somehow? Can you try full path to pip?

Comment: But when I execute same commands from `docker run -ti centos` everything is fine. What's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

As it has already been mentioned by [@rkosegi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1121249/rkosegi), it must be a `PATH` issue. The following seems to work:

```
FROM centos
ENV PATH /opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
RUN yum install -y centos-release-scl
RUN yum install -y rh-python36
RUN scl enable rh-python36 bash
RUN pip install django
```

I "found" the above `PATH` by starting a `centos` container and typing the commands one-by-one (since you've mentioned that it is working).

---

There is a nice explanation on this, in the slides of [BMitch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/596285/bmitch) which can be found here: [sudo-bmitch.github.io/presentations/dc2018/faq-stackoverflow.html#24](https://sudo-bmitch.github.io/presentations/dc2018/faq-stackoverflow.html#24)

> ## Q: Why doesn't RUN work?
>
> Why am I getting `./build.sh` is not found?
>
> ```
> RUN cd /app/srcRUN ./build.sh
> ```
>
> - The only part saved from a RUN is the filesystem (as a new layer).
> - Environment variables, launched daemons, and the shell state are all discarded with the temporary container when pid 1 exits.
> - Solution: merge multiple lines with `&&`:
>
>   ```
>   RUN cd /app/src && ./build.sh
>   ```

Answer (score 0):

I know this was asked a while ago, but I just had this issue when building a Docker image, and wasn't able to find a good answer quickly, so I'll leave it here for posterity.

Adding the `scl enable` command wouldn't work for me in my Dockerfile, so I found that you can [enable scl packages without the scl command](https://linuxdesktops.soton.ac.uk/softwarecollections.html#using-scl-without-the-scl-command) by running:

`source /opt/rh/<package-name>/enable`.

If I remember correctly, you won't be able to do:

```
RUN source /opt/rh/<package-name>/enable
RUN pip install <package>
```

Because each `RUN` command creates a different layer, and shell sessions aren't preserved, so I just ran the commands together like this:

`RUN source /opt/rh/rh-python36/enable && pip install <package>`

I think the scl command has issues running in Dockerfiles because `scl enable <package> bash` will open a new shell inside your current one, rather than adding the package to the path in your current shell.

Edit:

[Found](https://serverfault.com/a/851154/520883) that you can add packages to your *current shell* by running:

```
source scl_source enable <package>
```