# Problem making ruby available to Debian9 image

Tags: ruby, linux, docker, authentication

I have followed [these](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/walkthroughs/deploy/ruby/digital_ocean/nginx/enterprise/install_language_runtime.html) instructions to install `ruby` on a `debian9` image (I need an older version of `ruby`, namely `2.1.5`)

I have also included an extra step, to make it available upon login to all users, i.e.

```
echo "source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh >> /etc/profile"
```

So now, when I run my container after logging in to a terminal, `ruby` is available:

```
$ docker run -ti registry/container:tag bash
root@f6805551226c:/# ruby -v
ruby 2.1.5p273 (2014-11-13 revision 48405) [x86_64-linux]
```

However, when I run my container without an explicit login, `ruby` is not available apparently because the file is not sourced

```
docker run -it registry/container:tag ruby -v
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:344: starting container process caused "exec: \"ruby\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.
```

How can I address this?

Answer (score 0):

`/etc/profile` just works when user login into the shell:

`docker run -it registry/container:tag ruby -v` will just set `ruby -v` as the `PID1` of container, not use the `shell` as the `PID1` of container, so `/etc/profile` will not work.

Only next which will work:

```
docker run -it registry/container:tag bash -c "ruby -v"
```

When you use `docker run -ti registry/container:tag bash`, the `PID1` is bash, so `/etc/profile` will make effect, so you can have ruby in path.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you can solve these problems by using the [`ENV`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#env) instruction and setting the `PATH` variable yourself. It has worked for me at this question: [Why dockered centos doesn't recognize pip?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55059724/1561148) and as a practice it is also mentioned at Docker docs:

> ## [Best practices for writing Dockerfiles](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#env)
>
> #### ENV
>
> To make new software easier to run, you can use `ENV` to update the `PATH` environment variable for the software your container installs. For example, `ENV PATH /usr/local/nginx/bin:$PATH` ensures that `CMD ["nginx"]` just works.